# How to add OpenID to a php site?

Tags: php, openid

I absolutely love StackOverflow's usage of OpenID for registration. How would I go about adding this to my site? It is PHP based. I went to openid.net and looked at the libraries there, but could find little in the way of documentation or examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This tutorial was helpful for a previous project I worked on using PHP and OpenID.  It has an example app.

http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581

[image]
<sub>(source: [zend.com](http://devzone.zend.com/images/articles/3581/image3.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://openidenabled.com/files/php-openid/docs/2.1.3/OpenID/_Auth---OpenID---Consumer.php.html) and [examples](http://openidenabled.com/files/php-openid/repos/2.x.x/examples/).

Answer (score 0):

OpenID is great, but have one big disadvantage. Let's imagine that I'm having Google account and Yahoo account. I will login using Google and then I will try to login using Yahoo. And it will be different accounts; it's really difficult to remember what openID provider I was using for registration... So, be careful with OpenID on entertainment websites, but it is still ok for developers websites.

Check OpenId class from Zend Framework.

Comment: Ya, but you could associate both accounts to prevent this.

Comment: Yeah you can, but how could you know that user associated to these account is the same people? If user has deleted all cookies - it is impossible. :(

Comment: The only way is to do like stackoverflow do. Put "Add OpenID" button into user profile.

Comment: For sites that use email addresses as usernames, do you forget if you logged in with your gmail account or your yahoo mail?