# What is Open ID ? How to implement on my own blog post?

Tags: asp.net, openid

I have a website and I wanted to become an open ID publisher. How to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow people to log on to your site with Open ID? Or do you want to provide the authentication so that people can use your service to log onto other sites (e.g. like what Google, Microsoft, and others are doing)?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097388/how-to-add-openid-to-a-php-site

Comment: Not really.. The other one's for PHP, this one's for ASP.NET!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your exact requirements, you might want to try [OpenID delegation](http://wiki2008.openid.net/Delegation) instead. You can then use your website as a layer of abstraction over a third party provider.

Comment: Ah, new thing learned today!
Cheam and simple way to get your own OpenID :D I like it!

Answer (score 1):

As you're building for asp.net - take a look at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/). It's a free, open-source library that can make your asp.net webrite an OpenID provider (your website can be used to identify you) or a relying party (users can log in on your website using OpenID).

In fact, StackOverflow uses it as well, and so do I. It has a number of examples, and it's pretty reliable and secure.. Definitely recommended! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run your own identity server, then a good place to start looking is [here](http://wiki.openid.net/Run-your-own-identity-server). I run [phpMyID](http://siege.org/projects/phpMyID) on my site that acts as an openID server for me, it was easy to set up, seems to work, and no-one has stolen my identity ..yet.